# Package validation method in a class (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation

Hey I'm trying to make my app code look better and more organized. Right now I have a validation inside form's component. How can I make a new class and use this validation method in my form-group?

I will post my code:

```
export class AddMovieComponent implements OnInit {


  movieForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: DataService,
  ) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.movieForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required, this.titleValidator.bind(this)]],
     ...
  }

  titleValidator(control: AbstractControl) { --> I want this method in a CustomValidators class
    if (control && (control.value !== null || control.value !== undefined)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.dataService.getTitles().length; i++) {
        if (control.value == this.dataService.getTitles()[i]) {
          return {
            isError: true
          };
        }
      }
      return null;

    }
  }
```

I tried to make a new class and just add the validation method but that just went wrong whole syntax went bad. I hope someone can give me direction here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new service and add the method in the service. Then inject the service where you want to use the method like so:

Component that uses the service:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  // you might need this next line in your case
  myService.titleValidator = myService.titleValidator.bind(this)
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.movieForm = this.fb.group({
    title: ['', [Validators.required, this.myService.titleValidator()]],
   ...
}
```

and the service looks like this:

```
@Injectable({                  
  providedIn: 'root' // this line means you don't need to add it to a providers array and it will be loaded on demand and is accessible at the root level, it creates a single instance of the service that is accessible anywhere
})                             
export class MyService {                           
  constructor() { }           
  titleValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    // blah blah
  }       
}
```

You could alternatively just create a class and *export it* (export class MyClass) in the file in which it is declared and *import it* in the component that uses it. But a service is more common in the Angular world.

Comment: so if i create a new class i need also to add it to the component where the form froup is? how?

Comment: in the class file do export class ClassName ... and in the component import it ... import ClassName from './path'